# Converting to maven project generates a pom.xml with problems

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

i know this subject has already been discussed on other post but after tried a lot of their proposition i now come to you .

The problem is simple (and not) , when i convert my project to a maven project ( even if the project is empty) the pom.xml generated has errors in it .

You can see my pom.xml :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>Myproject</groupId>
<artifactId>Myproject</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Also in my company we use a proxy  so here it is :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <settings>
  <proxies>
  <proxy>
  <id>myid</id>
  <active>true</active>
  <protocol>http</protocol>
  <host>myproxy</host>
  <port>8080</port>
  </proxy>
  </proxies>
  </settings>
```

And then i got the error :

> Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:pom:2.5 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): connect timed out

As i searched , my settings.xml is correctly placed .
If you have any idea , please help me cause as far as i searched , nothing resolved my problem :)

Answer (score 0):

let me guess here, maven used by eclipse is not same as used by commandline. So, its settings.xml is also not the same. In eclipse go to,

```
windows -> preferences -> maven -> user settings
```

and check if eclipse maven is using correct file. If it is, then there is some issue with either in format/entries of settings.xml or some kind of network/firewall issue.

Comment: thanks a lot , the problem was that i had wrote the correct path but starting with a D instead of a d  ... Anyway, thanks a lot !